# Virtual memory allocation in cluster - line command

Tags: memory-management, cluster-computing

I`m running a code on a computer cluster with 24 nodes, 12 processors each one and something about 64Gb memory each node. The commands I'm using to launch it are the following

```
#!/bin/sh
#PBS -N cclit
#PBS -l walltime=288:00:00 
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=1
#PBS -j oe
#PBS -m n
#PBS -l mem=60000mb
```

Unfortunately I realized that my code need at least a virtual memory which is 120000mb. What I tried to do has been to modify the above commands as

```
#!/bin/sh
#PBS -N cclit
#PBS -l walltime=288:00:00 
#PBS -l nodes=2:ppn=2
#PBS -j oe
#PBS -m n
#PBS -l mem=120000mb
```

But it doesn't seem to work... It stops again at the same point telling me that virtual memory is not sufficient. 
My code is not parallelized, meaning that only 1 processor is needed. What happens when the memory of a node is totally used?? I guess Im doing something wrong with '#PBS -l mem=120000mb', or probably I need some other command... I tried to look for a solution on the web but I didn t find anything..

Can you help me?

Thanks Mirko.